# biblatex style with just commas and date at the end?

Tags: biblatex, french

I have a very basic question. I need to have a biblatex style that fits the requirements from a French publisher.
[image]
In a nutshell :

- mostly commas between elements of the reference, no points, no colons.
- date at the end (no brackets around the date)
- no "in: " before journal names
- extensive use of op. cit and ibid. (not ibidem) for repeated citations.
- note style (= complete references in first occurrences)

Typically, for a book :
Name, First name, *Title*, Address, Publisher,date.

So, unless I'm wrong, it needs to be one of the verbose styles but I am at a loss for find one that would do that "out of the box". I have read the ext-verbose doc and can see ways of achieving the result, but there might a more immediate solution in the available styles. I'd much appreciate your input if you think of something I have not seen! Thanks in advance!

Or, alternatively, should I consider tweaking one of the ext-verbose styles, by renewing commands in the preamble, in order to achieve that?

Best regards,
M

——-
Edit 1 : here is my MWE ; the bib file is the standard one.
(http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib)
The renewcommand newunitpunct works for most of the fields, the macro is the one that was suggested by @moewe elsewhere

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% I left the generic settings and added a newunitpunct instruction:
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
% the following to replace colons by commas between address and publisher, I'm not sure it's right this way :
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%from standard.bbx
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%instead of \addcolon\space
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}
\begin{document}


\section*{\cmd{footcite} examples}

% The initial citation of an entry includes all the data.
This is just filler text.\footcite{aristotle:anima}
This is just filler text.\footcite{averroes/bland}
This is just filler text.\footcite[26]{aristotle:anima}
This is just filler text.\footcite[59--61]{averroes/bland}
This is just filler text.\footcite{aristotle:anima}
This is just filler text.\footcite{aristotle:anima}
This is just filler text.\footcite[25]{aristotle:anima}
This is just filler text.\footcite[25]{aristotle:anima}

\clearpage

This is just filler text.\footcite{kant:kpv}
This is just filler text.\footcite{kant:ku}
This is just filler text.\footcite[24]{kant:kpv}
This is just filler text.\footcite[59--63]{kant:ku}

\clearpage

\section*{\cmd{autocite} examples}
This is just filler text \autocite{aristotle:rhetoric}.
This is just filler text \autocite{averroes/bland}.
This is just filler text \autocite{aristotle:anima}.
This is just filler text \autocite[55]{aristotle:anima}.
This is just filler text \autocite[55]{aristotle:anima}.

\clearpage
\printshorthands
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

——-- Edit2 (and sorry I had posted the new edit as an answer!)

Thanks for your helpful comments!
It might not be "nice" in terms of coding, but I achieve most of what was wanted with the following redefinitions, on the ext-verbose-trad3 style. I still use the standard bib file http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib
and I have reduced my MWE, and updated with moewe's helpful suggestions.
If you see errors I have not seen, please let me know!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-verbose-trad3,backend=biber, articlein=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% specific settings:
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcoma\space}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `ext-verbose` style is probably the best place to start for sure. I would play around with that and post a minimal document that outlines the bits that don't work and we can help you with that.

Comment: More likely than not there is no ready-made style out there that does exactly what your publisher wants. The requirements stated so far are not detailed enough to be sure, but I wouldn't know of a style that implements this out of the box. Many of the points you mention can, however, be achieved with `biblatex` standard styles with reasonable effort. (Some might be more tricky depending on what you need.) ...

Comment: ... I suggest you start with a style of the `verbose` family (look for files 70 to 76 in https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) and then modify it as needed. A good start is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864. But you will find plenty more questions about specific requirements on this site. If you cannot find any suitable question, don't hesitate to ask one. Just make sure to include a usable example document that shows the status quo and explain what you need as detailed as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the first replies, I'll post a MWE with different kinds of references. Regarding the three suggestions, I achieve a good part of what is needed with '\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{, }' in ext-verbose-ibid but I still have the colon between address and publisher. More to come, but in the meantime thanks @AlanMunn and moewe, this is much appreciated!

Comment: The more idiomatic choice would be `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}` instead of `\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{, }`. If you use `biblatex`'s `\add...` commands instead of the raw comma, `biblatex` can try and avoid double punctuation.

Comment: thanks @moewe! I have uploaded a MWE and a screen capture from a book. I'm not sure about the macro, but it seems to do the job in most cases. The bib file is the one in the biblatex examples (I have included the link above)

Comment: Contrary to the comments you got under your now deleted answer, I think the second edit should be an answer. If that is the code you ended up using and if you have no specific question about it, then it is much more useful to have it as a stand-alone answer. Maybe formulate the intro text more confidently. Please also consider accepting your answer (after a possible mandatory waiting period) to show that you no longer require immediate assistance.

Comment: thanks a lot for the input, @moewe As I'm new here, and there were these comments, I just complied, but the solution in edit2, based mostly on your suggestions, seems to work well. I'll test it again in longer documents, to see if nothing unusual happens in the footnotes, and will do just what you suggest. Thanks for your time!